# Libre office conditional sum no more works for newer versions

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I'm using for a long time a spreadsheet in LibreOffice Calc with formulas of this type:

```
{=SUM( (H27:H3001=1)*(MONTH(A27:A3001)=N20)*J27:J3001 )}
```

to perform a conditional sum over a range of cells, but from version 5 I get the '#value!' error, so I can't use newer versions of the product.
Is there a way to make compatible the formula with newer versions?
(The formula works on Excel too).

Thank you

Comment: Please give a [complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the input values and formula where this behavior occurs.  Also, what is the version?

Comment: [Here a sample with the error][1]  
         


[Here a sample WITHOUT the error][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k7Ck.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MF6fk.jpg
As you can see the only difference is the new entry in the cell A2068.
I'm using the fresh release of LO.
The last release I remember working is the 4.2.8.2

Comment: So the version is 5.2.3?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an array formula, try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT( (H27:H3001=1),(MONTH(A27:A3001)=N20),J27:J3001 )
```

From https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=35535:

> To sum with SUMPRODUCT: =SUMPRODUCT(criteria;criteria;criteria;…;sumfield)
>
> For example: =SUMPRODUCT(MONTH(A5:An)=1;YEAR(A5:An)=2010;C5:Cn=4;E5:En)

Comment: Thanks Jim for your answer, but the problem remains.
I think it's a different implementation of the function sumproduct(), becouse I verified that the function month() is the cause of the error

Comment: (`month()` applied to an empty cell returns the `#value!` error)

Answer (score 0):

The purpose can be solved this way:

```
{=SUMIFS($J$27:$J$3001;MONTH($A$27:$A$3001);$N20;$H$27:$H$3001;1)}
```

See also [this link](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/81588/libre-office-conditional-sum-no-more-works-for-newer-versions-italian/#81623).